# How to run tensorboard for tensorflow in AWS Sagemaker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard, amazon-sagemaker

I need to visualize real-time losses and metrics for a tensorflow model on AWS Sagemaker instance.
In a Jupyter notebook, I tried running

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir <path>
```

But nothing really happened. How can I get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the conda_pytorch_36 kernel (this is the one I used) and tensorboard is not installed by default so you need to run

```
!pip install tensorboard
```

Then you will get a blank screen when you run.

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir "./runs"
```

You can connect to tensorboard using your URL with notebook or lab replaced with proxy/6006

```
https://YOUR_NOTEBOOK_INSTANCE_NAME.notebook.ap-northeast-1.sagemaker.aws/proxy/6006/
```

Comment: it did not work. 
where is the path to the summary directory mentioned in that url?

Comment: the url to the notebook that i am using is https://rnn_recom.notebook.ap-south-1.sagemaker.aws/lab

so what URL do i need to use in order to get the tensorboard working?
and where do I mention the path of the tf summary directory?

Comment: I replaced %tensorboard with ! tensorboard and followed the rest of the steps, as you mentioned, and it worked for me

Comment: It seems to be that a recent change on SageMaker Notebooks causes this method to fail. The tensorboard URL opens but it stucks in persistent data loading state.

Answer (score 1):

install tensorboard if its not already installed

```
!pip install tensorboard
```

Then run the following two commands-

```
%load_ext tensorboard
```

and

```
%tensorboard --logdir <PATH TO TF SUMMARY DIRECTORY>
```

then run

```
https://YOUR_NOTEBOOK_INSTANCE_NAME.notebook.ap-northeast-1.sagemaker.aws/proxy/6009/
```

it worked for me :)